# How can I use lifecycle methods when a particular view is selected?

Tags: swiftui, swift5

I'm currently developing an application using SwiftUI.

This app has 2 Views controlled a Tab View.

I want to use these methods `sceneDidBecomeActive` and `sceneWillEnterForeground` in `SceneDelegate.swift` only when a particular view is selected.

These methods work irrespective of which view is selected.

How can I do this request?

---

SceneDelegate.swift

```
import SwiftUI

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    
    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
       
        let contentView = ContentView()

        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }
    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // I want use this print method only when FirstView is selected
        print("selected FirstVIew")
    }
    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }
    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // I want use this print method only when FirstView is selected
        print("selected FirstVIew")
    }
    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }
}
```

ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
   var body: some View {
        TabView {
           FirstView()
                .tabItem {
                        Text("First")
            }.tag(1)
           SecondView()
                .tabItem {
                        Text("Second")
            }.tag(2)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

FirstView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct FirstView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("FirstView")
    }
}

struct FirstView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FirstView()
    }
}
```

SecondView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("SecondView")
    }
}

struct SecondView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SecondView()
    }
}
```

---

Xcode: Version 11.7

Swift: Swift 5

Comment: SceneDelegate works as long as scene exists, it depends on scene not on specific view. You can react on this only in specific view, but you cannot prevent delegate callbacks once delegate created.

Comment: @Asperi, Thank you for your comment, I will look for another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SceneDelegate methods deal with App's life cycle, not a view's. Therefore you cannot "run" them when a view is selected.

What you can do though is use UserDefaults.

```
// When first view selected
UserDefaults.standard.set("First View", forKey: "selectedView")

// In SceneDelegate
func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    if let selected = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "selectedView"),    
             selected == "First View" {
        print("selected FirstVIew")
    }
}

func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    if let selected = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "selectedView"),          
              selected == "First View" {
        print("selected FirstVIew")
    }
}
```